# Problems w/Crystal Reports and 64 Bit machines

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I'm aware that this question may have been asked before, but I still haven't found any solution.

I have a .net application (.net 2005) with few reports done with crystal reports. My problem is that these crystal report print dialogue does not pop up in 64 bit machines.

I have found that [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385844/printdialog-showdialog-not-showing-the-print-dialog-in-windows-7-with-64-bit) but the problem is I do not write the code to pop up the dialogue box so that i cannot set UseExDialog to true. I have tried the service pack and many solutions proposed at the Internet but still no luck.

Pl Note that this is a windows based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1939320) solved the problem.

**Steps are,**

Make sure that app is compiled as 64 bit - not "Any CPU".

Make sure you are using SP1 for CR 10.2:

https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100006007872008E/crvs05sp1.exe

Then look in c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\sdk\v2.0\bootstrapper\packages\crystal reports\CRRedist2005_x86.msi

for SP1 MSI and use that to deploy the SP1 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This link suggests installing Crystal reports  XIR2 (or higher) + service packs:

- http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/130438-windows-7-and-crystal-report-viewer-xi-r2

Other links/other suggestions:

- [printdialog.showdialog(); not showing the print dialog in windows 7 with 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385844/printdialog-showdialog-not-showing-the-print-dialog-in-windows-7-with-64-bit)
- [Print Dialog Does not show up in Crystal Report Viewer on 64 bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519912/print-dialog-does-not-show-up-in-crystal-report-viewer-on-64-bit-machine)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using crystal report in 64 bit. and design crystal report with DSN than you have to set your DSN with 32 bit. in 64 bit operating system there are two types of DSN Settings.

or

second way you can set your web 32 bit compatible in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps below:

1- Open your old solution (that is created using Visual Studio 2005) in Visual Studio 2008,
2- Accept the conversion (from 2005 to 2008) while opening your solution,
3- Tick the backup checkbox and select your desired backup location,
4- Change your target platform from x86 (or Any) to x64,
5- After your solution was successfully opened,  your solution,
6- That's it, finished. Now run your project and you will see the  will be shown without any problem...